# SQL to XML with multiple values

Tags: sql-server, xml

Hello I'm new to converting SQL to XML. I have been trying to get this to work for the past few days.

```
SELECT Item.foldername AS "foldername", 
Item.status, 
Item.vhrid, 
Item.firstname, 
Item.middleinitial, 
Item.lastname,
dbo.getEnumDescript(Type, 'Type') AS title,
Item.email, 
dbo.getEnumDescript(OfficeLocation, 'OfficeLocation') AS Office,
       (
    select  id.id 'practices/practice/ID',
           id.name'practices/practice/Name'
    from [dbo].[Groups] as aprac
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PracticeGroups] as practices 
    on aprac.PracticeGroupID = practices.ID 
    where Item.vhrid = aprac.vhrid
    FOR XML path(''), type
)
FROM [dbo].[Att] as Item
FOR XML path, ROOT ('Item');
```

It returns this

```
<Item>
<row>
<foldername>foldername</foldername>
<status>1</status>
<vhrid>3</vhrid>
<firstname>firstname</firstname>
<lastname>lastname</lastname>
<title>title</title>
<email>test@test.com</email>
<Office>office</Office>
<practices>
  <practice>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>test1</Name>
  </practice>
</practices>
<practices>
  <practice>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>test2</Name>
  </practice>
</practices>
<practices>
  <practice>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>test3</Name>
  </practice>
</practices>
<practices>
  <practice>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Name>test4</Name>
  </practice>
</practices>
</row>
```

I'm trying to get it in this format.

```
<Item>
<row>
<foldername>foldername</foldername>
<status>1</status>
<vhrid>3</vhrid>
<firstname>firstname</firstname>
<lastname>lastname</lastname>
<title>title</title>
<email>test@test.com</email>
<Office>office</Office>
<practices>
  <practice>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>test1</Name>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>test2</Name>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>test3</Name>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Name>test4</Name>
  </practice>
</practices>
</row>
```

Any help would be thank full.

Comment: Which RDBMS? SQL Server, given the abundance of `[][][]`?

Comment: Yes SQL Server different tables within the database

Comment: @James, are you sure you want all ID & Name elements under a single practice tag? Looks.. unorthodox. :)

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of assuming that you want the XML to look like this:

```
<row>
...
<practices>
  <practice>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>test1</Name>
  </practice>
  <practice>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>test2</Name>
  </practice>
  <practice>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>test3</Name>
  </practice>
  <practice>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Name>test4</Name>
  </practice>
</practices>
</row>
```

I think this is the solution you're looking for (see my comments for where I've changed your code).

```
SELECT Item.foldername AS "foldername", 
Item.status, 
Item.vhrid, 
Item.firstname, 
Item.middleinitial, 
Item.lastname,
dbo.getEnumDescript(Type, 'Type') AS title,
Item.email, 
dbo.getEnumDescript(OfficeLocation, 'OfficeLocation') AS Office,
       (
    select  id.id AS [practice/ID],   --- here..
           id.name AS [practice/Name] --- here..
    from [dbo].[Groups] as aprac
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PracticeGroups] as practices 
    on aprac.PracticeGroupID = practices.ID 
    where Item.vhrid = aprac.vhrid
    FOR XML path('/practices'), type  --- and here.
)
FROM [dbo].[Att] as Item
FOR XML path, ROOT ('Item');
```

For obvious reasons, I haven't tried it myself, please let me know if it doesn't work.